# How do you print every match of a RegEx to a different file?

Tags: html, regex, r, html-parsing

I'm trying to do some text mining on Facebook chat data. I downloaded a full HTML file containing chat logs, but before I do any real text mining, I want to filter out my data to just a select few people. The general format of the document is: `<div class="thread">Person's name, my name blahblahblah many nested divs inside here </div>`. Several of these come back to back, and they comprise the entire chat log. Additionally, any given person I want to search for may have multiple threads in the document, and the entire doc is unindented/no newlines.

I wrote a regex using regex101.com that gives me the matches I want. It is as follows:

```
/(<div class=\"thread\">)(.{0,30}?(Jim|James|Bob).*?)(.*?)(<div class=\"thread\">)/g
```

You can test it out on this sample data:

```
<div class="thread">Abby iqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm <div> Hello world </div>xyz</div>abc<div class="thread">James iqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm <div> Hello world </div></div><div class="thread">Carl iqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm <div> Hello world </div></div><div class="thread">Dennis iqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm <div> Hello world </div></div><div class="thread">Kelly iqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm <div> Hello world </div></div><div class="thread">James iqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm <div> Hello world </div></div><div class="thread">John iqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm <div> Hello world </div></div><div class="thread"> and so on....
```

Now, I want R to search for this RegEx globally, and for each match, print the combined regions \\3 \\4 to a separate .htm file. This means it will contain the person's name and then the rest of the contents of the `thread`. My naming convention would be \\3_[match number].htm.

How can I print these contents of each separate match to a different file? Doing so would greatly decrease the amount of data I'll have to sift through during the main part of my analysis. I've tried doing similar stuff using the package `rvest` but my file is currently too big, so I want to break it down to just dozen or so threads I need.

Thanks.